# clinfo device cpu-gpu info

Tags: opencl, gpu, cpu

any one can tell me why Max work items for my gpu less than cpu and compute unit ???
is that mean performance for cpu is better than gpu

cpu : intel core i7 2.2GH
 gpu : amd radeon hd 6700M

```
Number of platforms:                             2
  Platform Profile:                              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:                              OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1084.2)
  Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Proces
sing
  Platform Vendor:                               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:                           cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callbac
k cl_amd_offline_devices cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing cl_khr_dx9_me
dia_sharing
  Platform Profile:                              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:                              OpenCL 1.2
  Platform Name:                                 Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor:                               Intel(R) Corporation
  Platform Extensions:                           cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd cl_khr_g
lobal_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32
_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
cl_intel_printf cl_ext_device_fission cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_gl_sh
aring cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing


  Platform Name:                                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Proces
sing
Number of devices:                               2
  Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU
  Device ID:                                     4098
  Max compute units:                             6
  Max work items dimensions:                     3
    Max work items[0]:                           256
    Max work items[1]:                           256
    Max work items[2]:                           256
  Max work group size:                           256
  Preferred vector width char:                   16
  Preferred vector width short:                  8
  Preferred vector width int:                    4
  Preferred vector width long:                   2
  Preferred vector width float:                  4
  Preferred vector width double:                 0
  Native vector width char:                      16
  Native vector width short:                     8
  Native vector width int:                       4
  Native vector width long:                      2
  Native vector width float:                     4
  Native vector width double:                    0
  Max clock frequency:                           725Mhz
  Address bits:                                  32
  Max memory allocation:                         536870912
  Image support:                                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:           128
  Max number of images write arguments:          8
  Max image 2D width:                            16384
  Max image 2D height:                           16384
  Max image 3D width:                            2048
  Max image 3D height:                           2048
  Max image 3D depth:                            2048
  Max samplers within kernel:                    16
  Max size of kernel argument:                   1024
  Alignment (bits) of base address:              2048
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                                     No
    Quiet NaNs:                                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:                       Yes
    Round to zero:                               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:                   Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:             Yes
  Cache type:                                    None
  Cache line size:                               0
  Cache size:                                    0
  Global memory size:                            2147483648
  Constant buffer size:                          65536
  Max number of constant args:                   8
  Local memory type:                             Scratchpad
  Local memory size:                             32768
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     64
  Error correction support:                      0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:            0
  Profiling timer resolution:                    1
  Device endianess:                              Little
  Available:                                     Yes
  Compiler available:                            Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:                      Yes
    Execute native function:                     No
  Queue properties:
    Out-of-Order:                                No
    Profiling :                                  Yes
  Platform ID:                                   02843864
  Name:                                          Turks
  Vendor:                                        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Driver version:                                1084.2 (VM)
  Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1084.2)
  Extensions:                                    cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomic
s cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_lo
cal_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_atomic_counters_32 cl_amd_device_attribute_query cl_amd
_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_d3d10_sharing cl_khr_d
x9_media_sharing


  Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                                     4098
  Max compute units:                             8
  Max work items dimensions:                     3
    Max work items[0]:                           1024
    Max work items[1]:                           1024
    Max work items[2]:                           1024
  Max work group size:                           1024
  Preferred vector width char:                   16
  Preferred vector width short:                  8
  Preferred vector width int:                    4
  Preferred vector width long:                   2
  Preferred vector width float:                  8
  Preferred vector width double:                 4
  Native vector width char:                      16
  Native vector width short:                     8
  Native vector width int:                       4
  Native vector width long:                      2
  Native vector width float:                     8
  Native vector width double:                    4
  Max clock frequency:                           2195Mhz
  Address bits:                                  32
  Max memory allocation:                         1073741824
  Image support:                                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:           128
  Max number of images write arguments:          8
  Max image 2D width:                            8192
  Max image 2D height:                           8192
  Max image 3D width:                            2048
  Max image 3D height:                           2048
  Max image 3D depth:                            2048
  Max samplers within kernel:                    16
  Max size of kernel argument:                   4096
  Alignment (bits) of base address:              1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:                       Yes
    Round to zero:                               Yes
    Round to +ve and infinity:                   Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:             Yes
  Cache type:                                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:                               64
  Cache size:                                    32768
  Global memory size:                            2147483648
  Constant buffer size:                          65536
  Max number of constant args:                   8
  Local memory type:                             Global
  Local memory size:                             32768
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     1
  Error correction support:                      0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:            1
  Profiling timer resolution:                    466
  Device endianess:                              Little
  Available:                                     Yes
  Compiler available:                            Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:                      Yes
    Execute native function:                     Yes
  Queue properties:
    Out-of-Order:                                No
    Profiling :                                  Yes
  Platform ID:                                   02843864
  Name:                                                Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670
QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Vendor:                                        GenuineIntel
  Driver version:                                1084.2 (sse2,avx)
  Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1084.2)
  Extensions:                                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_amd_fp64 cl_khr_
global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int3
2_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr
_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_gl_sharing cl_ext_device_fission cl_amd_device_at
tribute_query cl_amd_vec3 cl_amd_printf cl_amd_media_ops cl_amd_popcnt cl_khr_d3
d10_sharing


  Platform Name:                                 Intel(R) OpenCL
Number of devices:                               1
  Device Type:                                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Device ID:                                     32902
  Max compute units:                             8
  Max work items dimensions:                     3
    Max work items[0]:                           1024
    Max work items[1]:                           1024
    Max work items[2]:                           1024
  Max work group size:                           1024
  Preferred vector width char:                   1
  Preferred vector width short:                  1
  Preferred vector width int:                    1
  Preferred vector width long:                   1
  Preferred vector width float:                  1
  Preferred vector width double:                 1
  Native vector width char:                      16
  Native vector width short:                     8
  Native vector width int:                       4
  Native vector width long:                      2
  Native vector width float:                     8
  Native vector width double:                    4
  Max clock frequency:                           2200Mhz
  Address bits:                                  32
  Max memory allocation:                         536838144
  Image support:                                 Yes
  Max number of images read arguments:           480
  Max number of images write arguments:          480
  Max image 2D width:                            16384
  Max image 2D height:                           16384
  Max image 3D width:                            2048
  Max image 3D height:                           2048
  Max image 3D depth:                            2048
  Max samplers within kernel:                    480
  Max size of kernel argument:                   3840
  Alignment (bits) of base address:              1024
  Minimum alignment (bytes) for any datatype:    128
  Single precision floating point capability
    Denorms:                                     Yes
    Quiet NaNs:                                  Yes
    Round to nearest even:                       Yes
    Round to zero:                               No
    Round to +ve and infinity:                   No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add:             No
  Cache type:                                    Read/Write
  Cache line size:                               64
  Cache size:                                    262144
  Global memory size:                            2147352576
  Constant buffer size:                          131072
  Max number of constant args:                   480
  Local memory type:                             Global
  Local memory size:                             32768
  Kernel Preferred work group size multiple:     128
  Error correction support:                      0
  Unified memory for Host and Device:            1
  Profiling timer resolution:                    466
  Device endianess:                              Little
  Available:                                     Yes
  Compiler available:                            Yes
  Execution capabilities:
    Execute OpenCL kernels:                      Yes
    Execute native function:                     Yes
  Queue properties:
    Out-of-Order:                                Yes
    Profiling :                                  Yes
  Platform ID:                                   00401218
  Name:                                                Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670
QM CPU @ 2.20GHz
  Vendor:                                        Intel(R) Corporation
  Driver version:                                3.0.1.15216
  Profile:                                       FULL_PROFILE
  Version:                                       OpenCL 1.2 (Build 80752)
  Extensions:                                    cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_icd cl_khr_g
lobal_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32
_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store
cl_intel_printf cl_ext_device_fission cl_intel_exec_by_local_thread cl_khr_gl_sh
aring cl_intel_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing cl_khr_d3d11_sharing
```

why see three device type two for cpu and one for gpu 
opencl for intel for cpu or built-in gpu 
i have two display adapters :   AMD Radeon HD 6700M series
                                Intel HD graphic family

Comment: flagged it as a thread that belong to [su](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: what means Max compute units: 6 or 8 . is that means number of core for intel i have core i 7 ??? for gpu only 6 ??

Comment: Having larger workgroup size does not mean your CPU has more performance than your GPU. It just means that you can run bigger group of threads that can synchronize between eachother. You see two CPU devices because one of them is the AMD implementation for CPU and another is Intel's. Both of them run on the same hardware. The amount of compute units between CPU and GPU are not comparable. A CPU compute unit usually means just one core. Whereas GPU compute unit means something that runs a massive amount of threads at the same time.

Comment: Analogy, a Ferrari (CPU) might be faster than a truck (GPU). But does it have more "transportation" performance. No, because the Ferrari needs 200 trips to do the same as 1 trip of the truck (GPU) that does all the work at once.

Comment: what do you men two cpu  one for AMD implementation  and another is Intel's. why two because install two driver ???
i know there are two gpu one intel built in and other amd radeon ,i switch between them .
A CPU compute unit usually means just one core. Whereas GPU compute unit means something that runs a massive amount of threads at the same time.
can i know how many core in gpu or number of threads that run in gpu

Answer (score 2):

*"How many cores/processing elements/hardware threads does my GPU have?"* is a very frequently asked question for new GPGPU users. My usual response is *"Why do you care?"*. There is no way to query the number of processing elements that a device has using the OpenCL API. Exactly what constitutes a processing element and a compute unit differs greatly between different architectures.

The reality is that it really doesn't matter how many processing elements your device has, since using this metric is a really bad way of estimating the performance of the device anyway. If you really need to know how fast the device is for your particular application, then you should benchmark it (either with your application directly, or with a micro-benchmark that has similar properties to your application).

To answer your other question: you have two OpenCL implementations on your system that are capable of using the CPU, Intel and AMD. Therefore, both platforms will report the CPU as an available OpenCL device.

Comment: I am tired of this question. But I think we have to deal with it for long time... And in fact is a logical question to ask. People will still come from the CPU world and try to control manually each "thread" and know exactly the amount of them. Even when the GPUs will have millions of parallel cores....