# run opencl in microsoft vc using amd app or intel

Tags: visual-c++, driver, opencl, intel, amd-processor

In my computer with Windows 7 OS I have two versions of the OpenCL SDKS's from these vendors:

```
Intel
AMD.
```

I build my application using vs and add this path of lib for intel or amd. 
the library and include file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\lib

C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86
```

when use intel lib run gpu ok when use amd lib run gpu ok 
the question what difference between them ????

can i install only intel sdk that enough to run opencl for cpu and gpu 
my laptop have cpu : intel core i7 2.2GH gpu : amd radeon hd 6700M
the specification clinfo  [clinfo device cpu-gpu info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125440/clinfo-device-cpu-gpu-info#)

any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK gets you the include files (e.g, cl.h) and library (OpenCL.lib, which loads OpenCL.dll at runtime). It does NOT select which devices your program can access. Therefore using *either* SDK should get you access to *both* devices, as well as any OpenCL GPU devices in your system.

Your program can then select from the available platforms and devices to select which one (or ones) it runs kernels on.

Answer (score 1):

As per as AMD concern, AMD APP SDK compiler will be able to detect and run your OpenCL code even on Intel CPU, but vice-a-verse may not be true.

You can install only AMD SDK and use it for OpenCL Development.

Also Do check on which GPU is getting used by the kernel because even after having AMD GPU and  only AMD SDK, It may run your code on CPU (This could happen due to priority).

Comment: Intel OpenCL CPU driver works on AMD CPUs; the min requirement is SSE4.2.